# Self created templates not shown in the "New Project" dialog in the Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have created a C++ template with certain configurations in visual studio 2019, which is saved as a .zip file in the default `ProjectTemplates` folder. 
However, when I open the `New Project` dialog, I couldn't find my new template, the dialog only shows me 3 options under the left `Recent templates` tag which is not what I want, and I can't find my own template in the right Scoll-down menu.
Please tell me how to create a new project from self-created template.

Answer (score 0):

By updating my VS 2019 to professional edition, I managed to see my templates in the `New project` list. I am not extremely sure about the reason, just give a hint for this issue.